# Jasmine testing with circular dependent classes: Variable 'C' is used before being assigned

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, circular-dependency

I'm trying to set up unit testing for a module written in TypeScript, and I need to use Jasmine to build mocks and test the component. However, due to a circular dependence between two classes I need to utilize, I can't adequately declare them in Jasmine to make a mock.

While doing this, I receive an `Variable 'C' is used before being assigned. TS2454` which is legit. How can I generate mocks that are accurate without altering the model?

**model.ts**

```
export class A {
  public constructor(
    public c: C) {
  }
}

export class B {
  public constructor(
    public c: C) {
  }
}

export class C {
  public constructor(
    public a: A,
    public b: B,
    public id: string) {
  }
}
```

**spec.ts**

```
const a: A = {
  c: C
 };
const b: B = {
  c: C
 };
const c: C = {
  a: A,
  b: B,
  id: ''    
 };
```

Comment: In `spec.ts`, did you really mean to set the `c` property in the `a` object to the `C` **constructor function** (not an instance of `C`)? The `A` class defines `c` as an *instance* of `C`, not as a constructor function.

Comment: Ignoring testing for a moment, how would you expect to create an instance of (say) `A`? Because it requires an argument that's an instance of `C`, but to create an instance of `C`, you need to provide an argument that's an instance of `A`. (That's what the code says semantically. TypeScript's structural type system lets you bypass that by using something that's got the same shape as an instance but isn't constructed by the instance constructor, but if you're going to do that, use `interface`, not `class`.)

Comment: Yes you're correct however, I can't change the model and that's the problem. Making it interface was the first thing that came into my mind also. Without changing the model what would you suggest?

Comment: I think I'd just stick to suggesting changing the model to something that can actually be instantiated. :-) No other suggestions I'm afraid. Good luck with it!